# Conda doesn't recognize default and other channels

Tags: python, macos, conda

I've been using Conda on Windows for a while. However, I recently changed to MacOS, and I think there's something I might be doing wrong.

I usually install miniconda to work with conda command only. Recently, I tried to install the Deap package for python, available on the Conda-forge channel. So, I did:

`conda install -c conda-forge deap`

But, I get the PackagesNotFoundError for deep. I added the channel according to [conda-forge instructions](https://conda-forge.org). Then, I tried [uninstalling miniconda following the anaconda steps](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/). But, I can't install anaconda-clean (even though it is supposed to be available on the default channels).

I also realized that

`conda create -n envName python=3.7`

gives PackagesNotFoundError for python=3.7 (??).

This is from the `conda info` output:

```
channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

How is this possible? Did I messed something up? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you do Option A or Option B in uninstalling miniconda? Note that you linked to documentation about uninstalling Anaconda, but you had miniconda installed. Just removing the folder (Option A) should work in each case, though.

Comment: not all packages on conda-forge support arm64 yet. deap does not yet - you can find all supported platforms here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/deap